# How to run multiple insurance of MySQL in kubernetes

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes

we are trying to setup mysql server with below configurations.

3 mysql pods with sharing same persistence volume and data should be available across all pods and any pods can execute read and write requests and a load balancer to route the traffic to different pods based on load.
Hope kubernetes service will take care to route the traffic.
I tried master and salve method here master is only suitable for write and slave for read.
Can anyone explain which methods are available to full fill my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

For allow write in all pods os mysql you'll need to setup mysql in [**multi-master**](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/LATEST/features/multimaster-replication.html) topology, master-slave topology only will permit write on master pod.

Here are some reference for mysql multi-master topology:

http://dbadiaries.com/how-to-setup-mysql-master-master-replication

From this pods you can use [persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) to shared data between the pods

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/) you have a example of how setup mysql in master-slave topology, you'll need to adjust for your needs.

For handle the connection, you need to create a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for your pods, the [serviceType](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) will depends of how you'll expose your service.